# Portals besides the National Cancer Institute GDC Data Portal for downloading histology slides

Tags: cancer, machine-learning

I am downloading sample slides (in svs format) from the [GDC Portal](https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/) for a convolutional neural network model, but I also need normal tissue slides to perform classification.

There are some normal tissue slides that are adjacent to the tumors, but I'm looking for other easy to use portals on the internet where I can download different types of normal tissue (bone, connective, etc).

Can anyone recommend similar type portals where I can download svs files (or equivalent) of normal tissue samples?